# Spring + Hibernate drop tables on delploy

Tags: mysql, database, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

My option is set to:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

But I had this line in log (database was recreated):

```
2018-09-03 13:52:15.072  INFO 1751 --- [       Thread-3] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Hibernate: drop table if exists my_table
Hibernate: drop table if exists hibernate_sequence
```

I just added a couple of columns. This case is not reproducible: I've tried to add more column with correct update behavior.

What happened? Why Spring + Hibernate does not respect "update" value of the "ddl-auto" key?

Comment: Are you using Spring boot?

Comment: Reg, yes, I use Spring Boot.

Comment: You just added the property spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update to your application.properties in your resource folder?

Comment: Yes, file is located here: src/main/resources/application.properties, the property is inside of it. The file is being applied because I can connect to DB (credentials are located there), so this properties file itself seems to be used correctly.

Comment: I created an example locally - and saw that update is enforced as expected. You did not create a custom LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean by any chance?

Comment: No, its really some kind of mystics. After 10 new redeploys DB was not dropped, only updated. But not yesterday. Currently all I can do - make DB backups before each deploy.

Comment: Just a rule of thumb, try not to use spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update for production. Rather move to something like flyway. And set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate

Comment: Reg, I know, I know, but my DB scheme is very simple - just one tiny table. Anyway thank you for help.

Comment: this is quite mind boggling, Would you mind adding your pom/build.gradle? Also your property files? And any other Spring Configurations you might have?